# Is there a way to make a screen 100% height and width but when scaled down will always be large enough to contain children elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Essentially on desktop I want the background to cover everything (eg a landing page) but when the screen is made smaller I dont want content meant to be on that main screen to be spill out. Instead I'd like the background to then extend to encapsulate all children content. Essentially keep the children the same size but make sure the background (container) always stays just big enough to hold all of them.

I know I can use css and specify how things look at different sizes but I'd prefer to do this in a responsive way and not rely on me guessing the size of someone else's device.

Specifically trying to avoid a blanket 100vh since when the screen is shrunk The content can spill out the bottom.

Comment: You may need to use CSS  elements like max-width also max-height so you can make ratio size for included tags  inside wrapper.

Comment: Have you tried using viewport units like `100vh` and `100vw`? These don't require you to "guess" the size of the device.

Comment: What do you mean, "I'd like the background to then extend"?  Are you saying you want to make elements smaller and fit within their container?

Comment: @Brad yes, I want child items to fit their container (e.g. if i shrunk a screen using 100vh and 100vw there is a chance that whatever was inside that container will be too big and start squeezing out he bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Not completly sure I know what you want, but the following sample could be expanded to a `<div>` that wraps all the content or even added to the `<body>` if you like.

The CSS attribute `background-size` is using `cover` but this could be changed to [a number of other options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

```css
.containbg {
  padding:1em;
  background-image:url("https://via.placeholder.com/200/fda");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
}
.containbg img {
  padding:1em
}
```

```html
<div class="containbg">
  <p>Hello div test 1</p>
  <p>Nice to meet you</p>
</div>
This is a test gap
<div class="containbg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/879" /><br />
  <p>Hello div test 2</p>
  <p>Nice to meet you too</p>
  <p>And how has your day been?</p>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/879" /><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the background-image to 100vh